# how to check whether an android phone's camera support autofocus

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, autofocus

I know that with Camera.open() and getParameter to check focus mode will work.

But it seems open the camera will have a little bit of sound,which I don't want to ...

Any other way I can get whether the camera support autofocus or not ?

Answer (score 7):

another method will be to set a autofocus callback listner. in this case. the callback will have a boolean parameter stating if autofocus was successful. so u can jus check whether autofocus was succesfull and proceed further ..

EDIT:

I found this code somewhere on SO

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if(pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) && pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS)){
           // do something..
        }
```

`PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS` and `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA` are available from `API 7`.

Comment: Thanks. But to set autofocus callback listener, I still have to first get a Camera instance first using Camera.open , right ?